# thread local storage in assembly

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I want to increment a TLS variable in assembly but is gives a segmentation fault in the assembly code. I don't want to let compiler change any other register or memory. Is there a way to do this without using gcc input and output syntax?

```
__thread unsigned val;
int main() {
  val = 0;
  asm("incl %gs:val");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) Why can't you write '`val += 1;`' instead?  2) Do write that, compile it with `-O2 -S`, and examine the assembly output; you will discover that you are mistaken about how to access `__thread` variables.

Comment: @Zack can you write an answer about that?

Comment: val++ translates to movl $0x1,%gs:0xfffffffc, but when I do asm("movl $1, %gs:val") manually it translates to movl $0x1,%gs:0x8049f14. How to get address 0xfffffffc in my program.

Comment: @user1428099 You should look at `gcc -S` output to learn what you need to write, not `objdump -d` output. But really you should do it as I just described in my answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you really really need to be able to do this for some reason, you should access a thread-local variable from assembly language by preloading its address in C, like this:

```
__thread unsigned val;
void incval(void)
{
  unsigned *vp = &val;
  asm ("incl\t%0" : "+m" (*vp));
}
```

This is because the code sequence required to access a thread-local variable is different for just about every OS and CPU combination supported by GCC, and also varies if you're compiling for a shared library rather than an executable (i.e. with `-fPIC`).  The above construct allows the compiler to emit the correct code sequence for you.  In cases where it is possible to access the thread-local variable without any extra instructions, the address generation will be folded into the assembly operation.  By way of illustration, here is how gcc 4.7 for x86/Linux compiles the above in several different possible modes (I've stripped out a bunch of assembler directives in all cases, for clarity)...

```
# -S -O2 -m32 -fomit-frame-pointer
incval:
        incl    %gs:val@ntpoff
        ret

# -S -O2 -m64
incval:
        incl    %fs:val@tpoff
        ret

# -S -O2 -m32 -fomit-frame-pointer -fpic
incval:
        pushl   %ebx
        call    __x86.get_pc_thunk.bx
        addl    $_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_, %ebx
        leal    val@tlsgd(,%ebx,1), %eax
        call    ___tls_get_addr@PLT
        incl    (%eax)
        popl    %ebx
        ret

# -S -O2 -m64 -fpic
incval:
        .byte   0x66
        leaq    val@tlsgd(%rip), %rdi
        .value  0x6666
        rex64
        call    __tls_get_addr@PLT
        incl    (%rax)
        ret
```

Do realize that *all four examples* would be different if I'd compiled for x86/OSX, and different yet again for x86/Windows.

Comment: Nice answer. Are the extra prefixes for alignment in the last code?

Comment: @Jester They're to give the linker some extra space, so that it can replace the instructions you see with a more efficient sequence (but which consists of longer instructions) if that's possible.  See http://people.redhat.com/drepper/tls.pdf and http://www.x86-64.org/pipermail/discuss/2002-September/002829.html for gory details.